# ListTile image disappears when reordering list

Tags: flutter

I want to put an image as the leading element of a `ListTile`, but when I do, the reordering behavior is not optimal.  On top of being painfully slow (the majority of the slowness isn't because a leading image is being used, but it isn't helping things), the image disappears when dragging the `ListTile`, and flashes in and out if you click and hold the `ListTile`.  What is curious is that if I use a premade Flutter `Icon`, the disappearing issues don't exist.

What options do I have to correct this?

Dartpad gist [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=914fa1e4053256bbb220fe76b568ff26).

```
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Flutter code sample for ReorderableListView.ReorderableListView.builder

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// PNG base64 too big to include in SO question
const String _pngBase64 = 'YOUR_PNG_BASE_64_HERE';

void main() => runApp(const ReorderableApp());

class ReorderableApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReorderableApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('ReorderableListView Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: ReorderableExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReorderableExample> createState() => _ReorderableExampleState();
}

class _ReorderableExampleState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);

    return ReorderableListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      itemCount: _items.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          key: Key('$index'),
          leading: Image.memory(base64Decode(_pngBase64)),
          tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
          title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
        );
      },
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [How to cache memory image using Image.memory() or MemoryImage() flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963713/how-to-cache-memory-image-using-image-memory-or-memoryimage-flutter)

You can try to use this custom `ImageProvider` :

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CacheImageProvider extends ImageProvider<CacheImageProvider> {
  final String tag; //the cache id use to get cache
  final Uint8List img; //the bytes of image to cache

  CacheImageProvider(this.tag, this.img);

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(
      CacheImageProvider key,
      Future<Codec> Function(Uint8List,
              {bool allowUpscaling, int? cacheHeight, int? cacheWidth})
          decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(decode),
      scale: 1.0,
      debugLabel: tag,
      informationCollector: () sync* {
        yield ErrorDescription('Tag: $tag');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Codec> _loadAsync(
      Future<Codec> Function(Uint8List,
              {bool allowUpscaling, int? cacheHeight, int? cacheWidth})
          decode) async {
    // the DefaultCacheManager() encapsulation, it get cache from local storage.
    final Uint8List bytes = img;

    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0) {
      // The file may become available later.
      PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict(this);
      throw StateError('$tag is empty and cannot be loaded as an image.');
    }

    return await decode(bytes);
  }

  @override
  Future<CacheImageProvider> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<CacheImageProvider>(this);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    bool res = other is CacheImageProvider && other.tag == tag;
    return res;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => tag.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      '${objectRuntimeType(this, 'CacheImageProvider')}("$tag")';
}
```

Then use it like this in your code

```
leading: Image(image: CacheImageProvider(_pngBase64, base64Decode(_pngBase64))),
```

Comment: Good find, works like a charm!